# Any acc with eth is accessing my contrct restricted methods on rpstn ntwrk.It should give err but its not giving. On ganache its working as expected

Tags: web3js, metamask, ropsten

I created one project, which is working perfectly on ganache.
But whenever I deploy it on ropsten it is doing anything.
I will explain in brief

after opening my web app on browser if i try to call any method of my contract through web3, with any ropsten address in metamask my functions are getting called
which they shouldn't
because I put such restrictions using require statements in functions.
and this thing working perfectly in local network
functions are throwing error
but here
in ropsten, functions are just throwing transaction confirm messeges.
what can i do to fix this?
help me
Im new here.

github repo link https://github.com/swapnil7895/AgriBlockchainTrade

here is link of github project where i deployed my app https://swapnil7895.github.io/AgriBlockchainTrade/

Comment: here is link of github project where  i deployed my app https://swapnil7895.github.io/AgriBlockchainTrade/

Comment: Hi there. Do you have a link to one of the transactions that is succeeding, but which should be failing?